# Как получить запросы в Google в реал-тайме?

Tags: google-analytics

Имеется несколько серваков с Ubuntu. Нужно узнать, сколько пользователей, проживающих на территории Х, запросило товар Y в поисковой строке Google в период с T по настоящее время. Требуется построить 2D график и в реал-тайме его апдейтить.

Можно ли такое реализовать в принципе?
Если да, то как получить запросы в Google в реал-тайме?
Какие языки и технологии необходимо знать?
Пишу сам на С/C++.

Comment: может это банально, но по-моему это надо узнавать у Google, смотреть, что они предоставляют, дают ли они такую статистику вообще. Поправьте, если не прав.

Comment: Хотелось бы какой-нибудь туториал почитать на хабре или еще где-то по этой теме. Есть сервисы Google Trends, Google Adwords, но я с ними не работал. И чем самому лазить по ним долго-долго, так, может, знающий даст наводку...

Comment: А вы пробовали? Насчет долго-долго не уверен.

Comment: вот, например, вроде бы разобраться за недолго можно https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-trends-api